# How to query from the result of a changed column of a table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select, sql-insert

So I have a string time column in a table and now I want to change that time to date time type and then query data for selected dates.

Is there a direct way to do so? One way I could think of is 
1) add a new column 
2) insert values into it with converted date 
3) Query using the new column

Here I am stuck with the 2nd step with INSERT so need help with that

```
  ALTER TABLE "nds".”unacast_sample_august_2018" 
    ADD COLUMN new_date timestamp

-- Need correction in select statement that I don't understand
    INSERT INTO "nds".”unacast_sample_august_2018” (new_date)
    (SELECT new_date from_iso8601_date(substr(timestamp,1,10))
```

Could some one help me with correction and if possible a better way of doing it?

Tried other way to do in single step but gives error as `Column does not exist new_date`

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT from_iso8601_date(substr(timestamp,1,10)) FROM "db_name"."table_name") AS new_date
WHERE new_date > from_iso8601('2018-08-26') limit 10;
```

AND

```
SELECT new_date = (SELECT from_iso8601_date(substr(timestamp,1,10)))
FROM "db_name"."table_name"
WHERE new_date > from_iso8601('2018-08-26') limit 10;
```

Could someone correct these queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as follows:

```
select *
from 
(
  SELECT from_iso8601_date(substr(timestamp,1,10)) as day,*
  FROM "db"."table"
 )
WHERE  day > date_parse('2018-08-26', '%Y-%m-%d')  
 limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those steps, just use `USING CAST` clause on your `ALTER TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (my_timestamp) AS
    VALUES ('2018-09-20 00:00:00');

ALTER TABLE foobar 
    ALTER COLUMN my_timestamp TYPE timestamp USING CAST(my_timestamp AS TIMESTAMP);
```

If your *string timestamps* are in a correct format this should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please check my edits and correct my query. I want to minimize the steps.